# How to give total kerberos authentication details in pyspark code?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to read a file on HDFS using pyspark. The file is present in a different HDFS cluster and server to the one where Pyspark job is running i.e. my pyspark job has to read a file which is present on a different hadoop cluster. In order to access the file, I have to go through keytab authentication for which I wrote the below code:

```
sc_conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext()

sc_conf.setAppName("check_conn_cross_cluster")
sc_conf.setMaster("yarn")
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.memory', "2g")
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.cores', "2")
sc_conf.set('spark.yarn.keytab', "/home/devusr/devusr.keytab")
sc_conf.set('spark.yarn.principal', "devusr@HADOOP.COMPANY.COM")
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.instances', "1")

try:
    sc.stop()
    sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
except:
    sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)
```

The keytab & Principle are of the cluster where the file exists. What I don't understand is where do I provide the rest of the keytab, kdc, realm details which are given below What I don't understand is where do I provide this information in the code:

```
1. "hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos"
2.  System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", kdc);
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", realm);
3.  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(user, keyPath);
4. If I have to pass the config files like core-site.xml & hdfs-site.xml files, do I have to pass the config files of the server where the file exist ?
```

I have written the code in plain java to access a file on Hadoop cluster by giving all the necessary details without using spark in the code. Now I have a requirement to write the same code in pyspark but I am confused on how to give certain details to the spark configuration to read a file which is present on a different server while my spark programs on another server. Could anyone let me know how can I add the necessary details in the code to access a file on HDFS from a different server.